# Shell Script to Execute Shell Script to All Subdirectories

Tags: debian, shell-script, scripting

I am making a script to simplify my daily tasks. Everyday, I have to grep for a few things inside a company server. It was okay, however, now, they have segregated each object into sub directories. I am looking for a solution in which my existing shell script will execute repeatedly into each sub directory inside a certain directory. How do I do this? I am quite new to Linux and still learning the ropes.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
MainDir=/path/to/dir/containing/subdirs
# cd into dir
cd $MainDir

for dir in $(ls); do

#fetch start time of uut
grep -i "01_node_setup" $dir/his_file | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out

#check if sysconfig.out exists
if [ -f $dir/sysconfig.out];
then
    grep -A 1 "Drive Model" $dir/sysconfig.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
else
    grep -m 1 "Pair0 DIMM0" $dir/node0/trans_file_prev/*setupsys* | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
fi

done

#cd back to where we started
cd $OLDPWD
```

A nice guy helped me with the script, and the script above is what came out. It worked alright however, the sst-logs.out file displays `binary file /some/subdirectory/` instead of the output of the grep. What is wrong in the script?

Comment: anyone who can help me? :(

Comment: Does the grep switch `-R` for recursive help?

Comment: @Marco, it might if the subdirectories contain only one each file name i am grepping to which is not the case. the subdirectories also have their own subdirectories which has the file with the same file name (e.g. history) which i do not want...

Answer (score 4):

find will save you:

```
find /your/dir/with/subdirs -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" ; /path/to/your/script.sh ;' \;
```

Comment: Thanks rush... Will also try this. I am looking for the lightest implementation.. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your script.

> ```
> cd $MainDir
> ```

Better make this `cd "$MainDir"`. Here this is not important, but it's a good habit to get into. If you leave a variable expansion unquoted, the value of the variable is split into words, and each word is treated as a shell wildcard pattern; so this command would fail if `$MainDir` contained whitespace or `\[?*`. Putting double quotes never hurts (unless you want splitting and filename matching to happen), and avoids these extra expansions. The same goes for command substitutions (`$(somecommand)`). **Always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions** unless you know you want splitting and filename matching.

> ```
> for dir in $(ls); do
> ```

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You almost never need `ls` in scripts. As explained above, the result of a command substitution is split into words that are treated as wildcard patterns, so `$(ls)` mangles whitespace and wildcard characters, in addition to the mangling of non-printable characters that `ls` may do. Listing the file names in a directory is built into the shell:

```
for dir in *; do
```

If you make that `for dir in */; do`, only subdirectories of the current directory are matched, not other kinds of files.

> ```
> if [ -f $dir/sysconfig.out];
> ```

You need whitespace on each side of the brackets, except when the character next to it is a shell punctuation character: `();&|<>`. And again, put double quotes around the variable substitutions (this goes for every other place where you have a variable substitution): `if [ -f "$dir/sysconfig.out" ];`

> ```
> #cd back to where we started
> cd $OLDPWD
> ```

This is useless: the process is about to exit, changing its current directory won't affect anything. Note that each process has its own current directory: changing it in a script does not affect the program that called the script.

---

Turning to the reason you asked this question, it isn't clear what you want. “`binary file /some/subdirectory/`” doesn't make much sense: you wouldn't get this message with a directory. For better help, copy-paste the error message. You should **always copy-paste error messages** when you ask for help online.

From your description, it seems that files have moved one directory level deeper. If that's the case, change the line `for dir in */; do` to

```
for dir in */*/; do
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways you could do this.  you could either run your existing script in a for loop, or use find and xargs, or perhaps even make use of grep's `-r` aka `--recursive` option.

The simplest is probably just to write a for loop wrapper around your existing script.  For example:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /path/to/top/level/directory

for d in */ ; do 
  pushd $d
  # call your script here
  popd
done
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. Will try this... Appreciate the help :) Can this be done to CD just one sub directory deep? Because the subdirectories have their own "history" subdirectory which contains the same file name.

Comment: as written, it only iterates through the first-level subdirectories of your top-level directory.  i.e. yes.  if you needed it to process every subdirectory below that you'd have to do something like `for d in $(find . -type d); do ...`

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement on @rush's `find` suggestion, instead of using the `-exec` switch, you can avoid adding the `cd` command by doing something like this:

```
find /path/to/dir/containing/subdirs -type d -execdir /path/to/your/script.sh \;
```

This way you can avoid the `for` loop in your original script altogether.